# Centrar contenido en iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

He tratado de centrar la imagen creando una clase, y tambien aplicar dentro del mismo codigo un text-align="center" incluso agregando un important pero no me funciona.

```
Object.keys(sections2).forEach(function (section) {
var file = "./files/".concat(id, "_").concat(sections2[section], ".png");
fileCheck(file, function () {
$('#' + section).html("<iframe src=\"".concat(file, "\" style=\" \" width=\"100%\" height=\"400px\"  /> </iframe>"));
}, function () {
$('.' + section).hide();
});
});
```

Este contenido forma parte de una pestañan que se carga en un modal, aquí estoy utilizando bootstrap...

Comment: ¿Dónde probaste ese `text-align="center"`? No es un atributo válido para etiquetas ni tiene el formato CSS adecuado, que debería ser algo como `style="text-align:center;"`. Aunque no tengo la certeza de que vaya a funcionar, pensando en que el archivo a cargar tiene estilos independientes. Por cierto, en lugar de `concat()` podrías usar [plantillas de texto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) para tener un código más legible y evitar la necesidad de escapar comillas dobles.

Comment: si ves dentro del iframe tengo el style="width y height, aqui agregue el align" pero no lo toma, el codigo lo tuve que traslipar con babel, es lo que me entrego, incluido el concat... gracias por el comentario

Comment: Los estilos de un iframe son independientes